# SBT: code generation in multi module project

Tags: sbt, code-generation, multi-module

Can you help me to find a working example of code generation in a multimodule sbt project?

I.e. I have code generator as an object with def main() in one module and a class, which uses geenerated code in the second

I see examples of code generations, but I don't know how to use this in multi module

Comment: See my project on github: [mvn2sbt](https://github.com/ajozwik/mvn2sbt)

Comment: I don't see code generation here

Comment: https://github.com/ajozwik/mvn2sbt/blob/master/build.sbt#L40